# log log model: multicollinearity and interpretation

Tags: model, multicollinearity, linear

I would like some advice on a small multiple regression model. 
The model is a log - log one, with log(investments) as the dependent variable.
My issue is that I would like to introduce log(GDP per capita) and log(population) as independent variables.

It yields: log(investments) = B0 +B1log(GDP per capita) + B2log(population)
My goal is to interpret in % how GDP per capita affects investments, holding population constant.

Is this model valid? I am aware that log(GDP per capita) = log(GDP) - log(population). Would it rig the results by provoking a bias on coefficients?
Indeed, it would imply B1log(GDP) - B1log(population) + B2log(population) = B1log(GDP) + (B2-B1)log(population). Does it mean that B1 and B2 are not relevant to estimate the effects of log(GDP per capita) and log(population)? 
However, log(GDP per capita) and the log(population) are almost uncorrelated in my dataset.

Thank you all for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is this model valid?" is a rather vague question. From reading your text, I see three separate issues:

1. Is it ok to take the log of variables?

   - A: Yes
2. When will adding another variable to the right hand side create a multi-collinearity problem?

   - A: You should not add a variable that is a linear combination (or near linear combination) of existing variables.
3. Will my regression estimate something useful?

   - A: Perhaps? This is the most complicated question. Standard ordinary least squares (OLS) will estimate a linear conditional expectation function. That's generally OK for straight forecasting, but a causal interpretation requires more assumptions and structure.

### Example of something NOT ok (because of multicollinearity)

Let's say you wanted to have `log(GDP per capita)`, `log(Investment per capita)`, and `log(Investment / GDP)` all as right hand side variables. Your data matrix would be rank deficient because one of your right hand side variables is a linear combination of the others.

$$ \begin{align*} x_1 &= \log(GDP) - \log(Pop)  \\ 
x_2 &= \log(Inv) - \log(Pop)\\
x_3 &= \log(Inv) - \log(GDP) = x_2 - x_1
 \end{align*}$$
$x_3$ is a linear combination of $x_1$ and $x_2$. You could include:

- A) $x_1$ and $x_2$ as right hand side variables.
- B) $x_2$ and $x_3$
- C) $x_1$ and $x_3$

And they would all, at a mathematical level, be equivalent regressions in the sense that you could transform the estimates of one into the estimates of the other. Tell me the results from (A) and I can tell you what the results of (B) and (C) would be etc...

As a practical matter, if you included $x_1$, $x_2$, AND $x_3$, some packages (eg. Stata) may detect this and throw one of your variables out, but you should not rely on that type of behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Following your explanation:
x1 = log(GDP per capita) = log(GDP) - log(population)
x2 = log(population)
So x1 and x2 can be included safely as independent variables, even if x1 = log(GDP) - x2?

Comment: @indeed Yeah, why not? Nothing wrong with it. On the other hand, whether it makes sense or not, whether you're estimating what you think you're estimating is another question.

Comment: I just had a doubt on whether log(GDP) could be considered a constant in this framework. But thinking about it, it seems obvious that it is not the case... 

My main goal is to estimate the effect of GDP per capita on investments, holding population constant.

Answer (score 2):

In a *log-log* model, effect is interpreted as $\%\Delta y = \beta_1 \% \Delta x$ which means $1\%$ increase (decrease) in $x$ values will cause $\beta \%$ increase (decrease) in $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am aware of the interpretation of coefficients using a log-log model (that's a key reason of the design of this one). However, I have doubts on the potential bias on coefficients by using both log(GDP per capita) and log(population) as dependent variables.

Comment: If the variables are correlated, it might be that the transformed variables (_log-value_), too will be correlated. Also transformation should be justified by checking if _log-value_ improves fit.

Comment: Population and GDP per capita have a coefficient of correlation of 0.08. It is -0.07 between log(population) and log(GDP per capita).

Comment: From small _coefficient of correlation_ value, it looks variables are uncorrelated.

Comment: Exactly. So it means that the coefficients produced by the regression are not biased by the model?

Comment: Just log transformation should not cause any issue unless the raw values of variables are correlated or something.

Comment: All right, thank you for your answer. I would have an additional question. As I have log(GDP per capita) and log(population), can the coefficient of log(GDP per capita) be interpreted as the elasticity, by holding population constant OR by holding log(population) constant (= in which cas it is not really meaningful).

Comment: Yes, you're correct. $Elasticity =  \frac {\% \text { change in investments }}{\% \text { change in GDP per capita }} = \frac {\% \Delta y}{\%\Delta x_{GDP}} = \beta_1 $; `population` held constant. If elasticity is greater than or equal to one, the curve is considered to be elastic. If it is less than one, the curve is said to be inelastic.